# Signing a Git commit with more than one author

Tags: git, gnupg

Is it possible to have a Git commit signed by more than one GPG key?

We do a lot of pair-programming and use `git-duet`, as well as [YubiKeys with GPG keys on to sign commits](https://www.engineerbetter.com/blog/yubikey-signed-commits/), so we can prove the identity of the committer no matter whose machine we are using. However, it'd be really great if we could also prove the identity of the other member in the pair.

Any ideas on how we could prove the identity of both members of the pair? This would be handy in regulated environments to prove that code has been seen by another set of eyes (and is thus less likely to contain sneaky backdoors).

Comment: Git is only going to *check* one key. So you'd need to arrange for that one key to be available only when multiple individuals agree to unlock its use. There's a description of this *concept* [here](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual.html#AEN385), but how you would actually use this in practice, I am not sure.

Comment: Does it help you? https://github.blog/2018-01-29-commit-together-with-co-authors/

Comment: It is possible to do since OpenPGP allows you to write two signatures from different keys, but you'll require a custom `gpg.program` to do this for you.

Comment: “to prove that code has been seen by another set of eyes”—I don’t get this part. You can only prove the presence of someone (by signing), not the *absence* of anyone else.

Comment: @Guildenstern the solution would be to prove the commit was by two or more people, not to prove the absence of anyone. You seem to be in agreement with OP, I don't understand the confusion.