# Git GPG signing for multiple authors

Tags: git, github, gpg-signature, yubico

Is there a way to verify multiple authors signed a commit using multiple GPG keys.

My teams already use Co-Authored-by trailers in the git commit message. For compliance reasons I'm hoping to verify each attributed author using GPG signing(GPG + physical security keys). I can't find any documentation on if this is possible so i'm hoping that the collective wisdom of StackOverflow has an answer.

Comment: https://github.com/hashbang/git-signatures

Comment: same question also asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64181711/signing-a-git-commit-with-more-than-one-author